# hide jQuery Validation error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I hide jQuery Validation Error message of a specific field?

In my "contact us" page I have four text boxes, one drop down menu and one `textarea`.  My last text box is shown or hidden depending on the value selected in dropdown menu.  All fields are validated by jQuery Validation plugin.

Now when this last text box is hidden by selection of dropdown menu I want to hide its jQuery Validation error message also.

How can I do this?

Comment: We really need to see your source code

Comment: You don't really need to hide the error message, since you should instead be removing the validation rule whenever that field is hidden.  There is no reason to validate an unused hidden field.  You should really post some code so we can help you.

Comment: how can I reopen my question to improve my question with code and more explanation

Comment: You are free to edit this question at any time.  Then click the "reopen" link.  If you don't see a "reopen" link, then click the "flag" link to let a moderator know.  BTW, I provided a working demo below for an alternate approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like my example below, by utilizing the `add` and `remove` functions of the `.rules()` method.  See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules

```
$('form').validate({
    // your other rules and options
});

var ruleSet = {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
}

$('#field').rules("add", ruleSet);

$('button').click(function() {
    display = $('#field').css('display');
    if (display == 'none') {
      $('#field').show().rules("add", ruleSet);  // show the field and add the rule set
    } else {
      $('#field').next('label').remove(); // remove any outstanding message
      $('#field').hide().rules("remove", ruleSet);  // hide the field and remove the rule set
    }
});
```

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jqg7s/